# How to elegantly implement oplog in typorm(Base on mysql)

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I have a very important table A, and I want to use another table B to record all (or optional) of the field values in table A.

eg:
entity table name => user(Assumptions)
'password' is the import field.

| user |  |
| --- | --- |
| id | int(11) |
| user_name | varchar(255) |
| password | varchar(255) |

oplog table name => user-log(Tentative)

| user_log |  |
| --- | --- |
| id | int(11) |
| changed | varchar(255) |
| old_value | varchar(255) |
| new_value | varchar(255) |

##### such as update example:

> table user:

```sql
insert into user (user_name, password) values ('Finance','password1');
insert into user (user_name, password) values ('Finance','password2');
```

> table user_log:

```sql
insert into user (changed, old_value, new_value) values ('password','password1', 'password2');
```

More:
user_log table can record other info, such as update person, update time...